# xcode7: file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode7, lipo

There are two floders named "Release-iphoneos" and "Release-iphonesimulator",and I use these commands to create common framework,but is still have some error "file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)"

> lipo -create "Release-iphoneos/Fxencrypt.framework/Fxencrypt" "Release-iphonesimulator/Fxencrypt.framework/Fxencrypt" -output "Fxencrypt"
>
> cp -R Release-iphoneos/Fxencrypt.framework ./Fxencrypt.framwork
>
> mv Fxencrypt ./Fxencrypt.framwork/Fxencrypt

lipo -info are these

> lipo -info Release-iphoneos/Fxencrypt.framework/Fxencrypt
>   Architectures in the fat file: Release-iphoneos/Fxencrypt.framework/Fxencrypt are: armv7 arm64
>
> lipo -info Release-iphonesimulator/Fxencrypt.framework/Fxencrypt
>   Architectures in the fat file: Release-iphonesimulator/Fxencrypt.framework/Fxencrypt are: i386 x86_64
>
> lipo -info Fxencrypt.framework/Fxencrypt
>   Architectures in the fat file: Fxencrypt.framework/Fxencrypt are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64